# GETPIVOTDATA in Googlesheets doesn't seem to be working when picking a date column (#REF error)

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get GETPIVOTDATA to work right while using dates.  I have looked at multiple questions here on SO that are for GETPIVOTDATA, but none of them use a date in a reference.

I can create a pivot table with the following data and pull out the total for a given division and subdivision.  But I can't crack the code to handling dates right in GoogleSheets version of GETPIVOTDATA, even though my code works in MS Excel.

this data comes from the googledocs supportpage: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6167538?hl=en

division    subdivision product number  number of units Date    price per unit
 
east    1   1   14  3/1/2018    $10
 
east    2   1   15  3/1/2018    $11
 
west    1   1   11  3/3/2018    $10
 
west    2   1   21  3/4/2018    $9
 
east    3   1   16  3/1/2018    $8
 
west    3   1   18  3/6/2018    $12
 
**east  4   1   11  3/7/2018    $9**
 
east    1   2   10  3/1/2018    $9 
 
east    2   2   9   3/9/2018    $13
 
west    1   2   12  3/10/2018   $10
 
west    2   2   15  3/1/2018    $10
 
east    3   2   12  3/12/2018   $9
 
west    3   2   16  3/1/2018    $12
east    4   2   12  3/14/2018   $9

The pivot table is anchored into H1 and the columns listed are 
division,   subdivision,    Date,   SUM of number of units
in cells H1, I1, J1, K1 respectively

```
23  =GETPIVOTDATA(K1,H1,"division", "east", "subdivision", 4) 
#REF!   =GETPIVOTDATA(K1,H1,"division", "east", "subdivision", 4, "Date", datevalue("2018-3-07")) 
#REF!   =GETPIVOTDATA(K1,H1,"division", "east", "subdivision", 4, "Date", DATE(2018, 3, 7))
```

It should return "11" which is the intersection of east, 4 and 3/7

The #REF errors return with "Field combination not found in pivot table for function GETPIVOTDATA" even though it seems like all of the fields are listed. As you can see, I can get my summary value if I use two division and subdivision, but not when I add the Date field.  I have tried multiple ways to match the datevalue in the pivottable.

I am flustered.  What silly thing am I missing here?  Please check that your answer actually works in GoogleSheets before suggesting it :)
Thanks!

Comment: Not quite the same.  My issue isn't not knowing the function.  The issue is trying to get a value when one of the column uses dates.

Comment: I am keying off multiple columns so I can't use a single VLOOKUP.  Please see the example data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the value argument (technically the `pivot_item` argument) for the date argument (`original_column`) must be *text* that matches the format of the date *as it is formatted in the SOURCE of the pivot table, i.e. in the data.*

So if the date item is formatted as `3/7/2018` in the original data, then, regardless of how you format the date in the pivot table, a formula that works would be:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA(K1,H1,"division", "east", "subdivision", 4, "Date", "3/7/2018")
```

If in the data, there is a subsequent reoccurrence of the same value but is formatted differently, e.g. `3/7` (no year), then as far as I can tell, the first occurrence of that value will be used as the reference format.  So the formula above would capture all `3/7/2018` data* assuming the first `3/7/2018` data point is formatted as such.

If another date in the data is formatted as `3/8 Thu` (first occurrence), then that's the text that needs to be used in the Pivot Item of the formula.

Google's definition of the Pivot Item is:

> pivot_item… - [optional] repeatable
>
> The name of the row or column
>   shown in the pivot table corresponding to *original_column* that you
>   want to retrieve.

It says the ***name*** of the row or column.  Maybe they were very literal about it, but most likely not, considering this function is borrowed from Excel, and Excel uses the *value* independent of its format.

*subject to the other pivot columns/items (division & subdivision)

Answer (score 3):

I know that I'm absurdly late, but this was bothering me as well and I could not figure it out.

I finally realized that the `GETPIVOTDATA` method uses the total rows, and will throw an error if the correct totals are not there.

Hopefully this helps people who find this like I did.

Comment: Your anwers solved my issue, thanks a lot! Suggestion to improve it: Be a bit more explicit., e.g.:

`Click on 'Show totals' for all variables in your pivot table`

Answer (score 1):

Combining answers from bsoo and Amos47 fixed it for me.

1. Need to make sure you have "Show Totals" ticked on your pivot table
2. For dates, don't use datevalue("2018-3-07") - instead use the text function to match the format that you have in the pivot table. This can vary based on the spreadsheet location. For example, if you are referencing a cell A4 you might use =GETPIVOTDATA(K1,H1,"division", "east", "subdivision", 4, "Date", text(A4,"yyyy-mm-dd")).

With dates, I find using either the iso 8601 format "yyyymmdd" or the text version of the month "dd-mmm-yy" helps to avoid errors if it switches between US and European format

Comment: Great suggestion of using the `text()` formula with the dates, this solved one of my issues